Google sheets: using 2 criteria INDEX MATCH with BYROW function
I would like to use INDEX MATCH in a BYROW function to populate an entire column with the output of the INDEX MATCH.
There are 2 criteria for the INDEX MATCH function.
Criteria 1 is in row 2 of the current column (indirect(ADDRESS(2,column(),4)), and is looked up in named rang SUG_Drawing.
Criteria 2 is in column 1 of he current row (indirect(ADDRESS(row(),1,4)), and is lookup in named range SUG_EXC_PN.
The function below outputs data from named range SUG_QTY when both criteria are met. This function works as shown in Column J
index(SUG_QTY,match(1,index((indirect(ADDRESS(2,column(),4))=SUG_Drawing) * (indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),1,4))=SUG_EXC_PN),0,1),0))

I want to use the BYROW function to iterate through the rows of criteria 2. So I ended up with the formula below:
=BYROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()+1,4)&”:”&ADDRESS(B1,D1,4)), LAMBDA(q,INDEX(SUG_QTY,MATCH(1,INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,column(),4))=SUG_Drawing) * (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(q,1,4))=SUG_EXC_PN),0))))

The issue is the output for every row is the following error “Did not find value ‘1’ in MATCH evaluation.”. As shown in column K
If I change the name, q, to a number I know works, the output for every row is the same. As shown in column L.
Desired result is for 1 function to be put in row k3, that then outputs the same data as in J3:J243.
Example spreadsheet

A combined match of Z100573 and _00530.400EI will output two values 2 and 12;  are we supposed to pick the first value just like how your current index-match formula is doing OR do we need to sum them or something?!

Just need to pick the first value. I have not scrubbed this data, and did not realize there were duplicates.

checking your 2nd fx - dont use ”. instead use ". it matters.

What is the difference between those 2?


You may try:
=map(A3:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(+filter(SUG_QTY,SUG_EXC_PN=Σ,SUG_Drawing=J2)))))



Thank you! Why is it better to use map function here instead of the byrow function?

you can just use byrow() as well in this specific scenario here...

Do I need to the if statement to make my original formula work? Or does the index match just not work? Would like to understand why my formula wasn't iterating

dont think its the index-match fault but again not exactly sure with the indirect+address thing you got going over there...

I am using an apps script to auto populate all the columns with this formula, so it needs to be very generic
